# "this" keyword not working for setting a Context

Tags: java, android

I am using a code in Android to play sound,
However, When I am playing a sound in a main class the following code works,

```
private void playSound() {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}}
```

while, If I execute this code in another class the code gives error on this line,

```
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
```

Here is the error,

> The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not
>   applicable for the arguments (AlarmReceiver, int)

I observer that My `Main Activity` class extends `Activity` while the other class extends `BroadcastReceiver` and I know that this is causing the issue but I have no idea how to fix this ?

Here is the complete code,

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        playSound();
    }


private void playSound() {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
    player.start();
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}}
```

what Am I suppose to write instead of `this` keyword to make it work in any class other than the `Main` ?

Comment: Try this.getApplicationContext()

Comment: there is no method as getApplicationContext when I try it in Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onRecieve method,  you get a `Context` as argument.  If you pass the `Context` to your `playSound()`method,  you can use that `Context` to create a `MediaPlayer`:

```
@Override public void  onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message Toast.makeText. 
    makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    playSound(context); //Pass the context to your playSound method. 
}
```

Then you'll need to update the `playSound()` method to receive a `Context`:

```
private void playSound(Context c) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(c, R.raw.a); //Use the Context c instead of using this. 

    //the rest of your code... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can pass the context to playsound(context)

```
private void playSound(Context mContext) {
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.a);
player.start();
player.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.release();
    }
});
```

hope this will help .

Comment: so would it work if i would call it like playsound(this) ? also, could you please specify the reason why it isn't working this way

Comment: MediaPlayer.create() needs a Context as first parameter.Activity is a subclass of Context thats why calling MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a); inside the activity is working .

Comment: but the problem is the same, how to pass context when follow your method. ? 
i did this playsound(this), but the error is same

Comment: @RileyWillow use Mohanads `playSound` method and look in your `onReceive` method, where you call `playSound();` you need to call `playSound(context);`

Comment: if you are in activity you can call it with this pointer .while if you are in AlarmReceiver you call it and pass the context parameter  in onReceive .